# What's the benefit of using both Cloudfront and Cloudflare?

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, cdn, amazon-cloudfront, cloudflare

I currently host my server on AWS and is using Cloudflare. I read a lot where people combining both Cloudfront and Cloudflare. What are some of the benefits in doing so (make it even faster)? I thought Cloudflare itself is enough (protection, distribute content, etc).

Also in the case of combining the two, am I going to get free bandwidth from Cloudflare?

Would appreciate any input.

Thank you.

Comment: That seems like a weird thing to do. I could understand if you set up both origin -> cloudfront AND origin -> cloudflare, and then have simple dns routing between to the two, or fail over dns. But to me even that seems unnecessarily complex (for little win).

Comment: https://redd.it/4u7os2

Comment: *"I read a lot where people combining both Cloudfront and Cloudflare"*  Where?  Are you sure it's not people "using both" in the sense of "for some projects, I use one, but for some projects, I use the other" ...?  Combining the two in parallel in a meaningful way would be impossible, since each of them uses their own DNS networks to send the browser to the nearest edge -- one or the other must be chosen *before* the routing decision.

Comment: For example this one. What's the reason they combine CDN with Cloudflare?  https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172606-I-already-have-a-CDN-provider-Can-I-still-use-Cloudflare-

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a significant advantage in using both CloudFront and CloudFare together.

However the performance  advantage you can get is having a caching edge closer to a specific user's country or location where only one of them has the presence. Still you need to configure load balancing at DNS level to achieve this with Geo based routing.

On the other hand if it's the utilization of free bandwidth from CloudFare, you can configure weighted DNS load balancing for it.